# Reading/opening file from filename in python

Tags: python, input

So I am trying to open a text file with python from the filename in input
I don't know what I am doing wrong. If someone could correct it that would be awesome! Thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/python
file = input('Enter filename: ')
f = open("file")
print(f.read())
```

Answer (score 1):

`file` is variable which value enter by User. 
But in code "file" i.e. string file is used to open file.

```
f = open("file")
          ^^^^^
```

But not do use build in function name as variable name.

```
>>> file
<type 'file'>
>>>
```

---

Demo:

```
>>> file_path = raw_input('Enter filename: ')
Enter filename: /home/vivek/Desktop/stackoverflow/1.txt
>>> fp = open(file_path)
>>> fp.read()
'I my Vivek,\nLearning Python\n'
>>>
```

---

Use **with** statement to open and write file.

Demo:

```
>>> file_path = '/home/vivek/Desktop/stackoverflow/1.txt'
>>> with open(file_path) as fp:
...    content = fp.read()
... 
>>> content
'I my Vivek,\nLearning Python\n'
>>>
```

**Note:**

Use raw_input() in Python 2.x

USe input() in Python 3.x